# How do I take a number associated with a word and have the word printed that number of times?

Tags: python, list, file, text

I have a text file with a list of words with a number and want to alter the list so instead of having the number next to the word, the word is printed that number of times.

So for example, with this list:

```
word, 2

for, 3

cat, 1

dog, 2

tiger, 1
```

I want it took look like this:

```
word

word

for

for

for

cat

dog

dog

tiger
```

For my python program I have this so far:

```
f = raw_input("Please enter a filename: ")
def openfile(f):
    with open(f,'r') as a:
       a = a.readlines()
       b = [x.lower() for x in a]
       return b

def fix(b):
    newlist = []
    for line in b:
        split_line = line.split(',')

print openfile(f)
```

What I want to do is take the number and tell the program to print the word that number of times and then delete the number but I am not sure how to do that.

If you have any suggestions, answers, or need clarification please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the file itself you can use [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) with `inplace=True` to change the file content:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.input("in.txt",inplace=True):
    if line.strip():
        w,i = line.split(",")
        sys.stdout.write("{}\n\n".format(w)*int(i))
```

Output:

```
word

word

for

for

for

cat

dog

dog

tiger
```

Answer (score 1):

You should realised that `print openfile(f)` would only print `b` returned by `openfile`... I think what you wanna is the **fixed-b**.

Pythonic:

```
def fix(b):
    for word, value in (x.split(',') for x in b):
        print '\n'.join(word*int(value))

fix(openfile(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in b:
    for i in range(int(line.split(", ")[1])):
        print line.split(", ")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make a slight change to your `fix` function that will append each item the number of times required to the `newlist`

```
def fix(b):
    newlist = []
    for line in b:
        split_line = line.split()
        for i in range(int(split_line[1])):
            newlist.append(split_line[0])
    return '\n'.join(newlist)
```

Finally, we change your `print` statement at the bottom to be:

```
print fix(openfile(f))
```

To write this to a new file, simply open a file in writable mode and write to that.

```
outdata = fix(openfile(f))
with open('myfile.txt','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(outdata)
```

Comment: Hey this really helped thank you! Do you know what would be the best way to take that and print it back to the text file or a new file?

Comment: Added a bit at the end to address this

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track, after spliting the line based on `,` convert the second element of `split_line` to `int` and then run a for loop for that much amount of times using `range()` function and then print the first element of `split_line` inside the for loop.

Also, some suggestions, you do not need to print `openfile(f)` , instead you should store that in a variable and then call the `fix` function on that variable. Also, if you want the new line in `newlist` and want to return the `newlist` , add the first element of `split_line` in newlist inside the for loop.

Example -

```
f = raw_input("Please enter a filename: ")
def openfile(f):
    with open(f,'r') as a:
       a = a.readlines()
       b = [x.lower() for x in a]
       return b

def fix(b):
    newlist = []
    for line in b:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        for _ in range(int(split_line[1])):
            print split_line[0]
            newlist.append(split_line[0])

b = openfile(f)
newb = fix(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing with just this:

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter a filename: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() != '':
            s = line.strip().split(',')
            if len(s) > 1:
                print "\n\n".join([s[0]] * int(s[1])) + "\n"
            else:
                print s[0] + "\n"
```